# Parse json data using java regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I have following type of json data and I want extract title from data using java regular expression

```
{
    "Title": "nice television for the price",
    "Author": "Jackie C",
    "ReviewID": "R3LDJA7HU2Q0FS",
    "Overall": "4.0",
    "Content": "The television was a refurbished one, and for the price, quality of pictures, sound, i am enjoying it at this very moment. I'm glad that I made a good choice thus far without having any problems with the television.  Thanks",
    "Date": "April 13, 2014"
}
```

please tell me for extract title from data what will be regular expresion

Comment: Do not use regex. Use a JSON parser.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the org.json library (import org.json.*) rather than using regex.

Comment: Thanx for quick reply             i alredy tried with json parser but i got  left '[ ' error

Comment: you can also use GSON for the same.

Comment: is there is any gui based tool available which can parse my json data easily,,,actually i want extract title from json file,,,

Comment: @AakashKag - This is one of 5 easy to find posts on this topic. Here's one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8750127/regex-for-parsing-single-key-values-out-of-json-in-javascript I'm not gonna DV you, but for future reference: Before posting on stackoverflow, it you aren't gonna google search your  question, at least search for it on stack overflow. It even prompts you to before asking anything each time.

Comment: Look at http://json.org.  There are lots of tools.  (But how / why you would a "GUI based tool" for parsing JSON escapes me ...)

Answer (score 3):

Use a JSON parser:

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

public class SOPlayground {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String j = "{\n"
                + "    \"Title\": \"nice television for the price\",\n"
                + "    \"Author\": \"Jackie C\",\n"
                + "    \"ReviewID\": \"R3LDJA7HU2Q0FS\",\n"
                + "    \"Overall\": \"4.0\",\n"
                + "    \"Content\": \"The television was a refurbished one, and for the price, quality of pictures, sound, i am enjoying it at this very moment. I'm glad that I made a good choice thus far without having any problems with the television.  Thanks\",\n"
                + "    \"Date\": \"April 13, 2014\"\n"
                + "}";

        JSONParser p = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject o = (JSONObject) p.parse(j);
        System.out.println(o.get("Title"));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
nice television for the price
```