# How to extract info from a json_like column from pyspark dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am doing analysis using **pyspark dataframe.**

There is one column was called: `json_data`. It looks like this:

[image]

Then I tried to convert it as a dictionary type format using following code:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
func = udf(lambda x: eval(x))
df_beer = df_beer.withColumn('json_data_new', func(df_beer.json_data))
```

After conversion, the new column `'json_data_new'` looks like this

[image]

Then I checked the data type of the old and new columns, both of them are still string type.
[image]

**Question: How can I extract the numbers linked to the key `"2_QTDE"` and save it as a new column?**

I knew it is a json like string, and I had a hard time dealing with this format.

I tried the python way using dictionary key, but it does not work.

So, I thought maybe I need to write a function to extract the numbers from the json_data_new:

```
df_beer = df_beef.WithColumn('newColumn', func_extract(df_beer.json_data_new))
```

How to properly define the function `func_extract`? Thanks!

Comment: Please [don't post pictures of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: Related to [How to query JSON data column using Spark DataFrames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34069282/how-to-query-json-data-column-using-spark-dataframes)

Comment: Although the linked dupe is in scala, the answer is essentially the same. You need to define a schema for your JSON, then convert it into a `StructType` using [`pyspark.sql.functions.from_json`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.from_json). After that you can access items from the struct using [`pyspark.sql.Columns.getItem(key)`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.getItem)

Comment: @pault  Thanks for the suggestion.  I wonder as the column type is string type, is it possible to use regular expression match?

Comment: @QianLi you probably *could* use regex, but I would not recommend it. Read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8750127/regex-for-parsing-single-key-values-out-of-json-in-javascript).