# RegEx validator for my JSON response incoming from REST webservice

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, regex

I want to create RegEx validator for my JSON response data, but I could not create successfully. What I am doing wrong? Please help me in this regards, thanks.

**If service returns an error, response json must be as follows;**

```
{
 "status":"error",
 "error":{
   "connection timeout"
 }
}
```

**If service returns a success, response json must be as follows;**

```
{
   "status":"success",
   "result":{
      "username":"msmumbucoglu",
      "password":"123456",
      "name":"Hacked By Mehmet:)"
   }
}
```

My regex is as follows:

```
(?:"status":")|(?:"result":")|(?:"error":")(.*?)(?:")
```

Comment: Why not use JSON.parse() to parse the data and simply check the status/result properties?

Comment: Parsing a JSON with a RegEx is strongly discouraged. See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8751940/5818232).

Comment: @AntoineBoisier-Michaud thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by parsing the string received (your json string) to a json object and then read the property `status` of this object.

```
const myJsonString = '{"status":"error","error":{"connection timeout"}}';    
const response = JSON.parse(myJsonString);

if (response.status === 'success') {
    console.log('OK');
} else {
    console.log('ERROR');
}

// in this case output will be: ERROR
```

Comment: Thank your reply man.I dont use regex.Your solution is more clever