# Extract json value with sed

Tags: json, regex, sed

I have a json result and I would like to extract a string without double quotes

```
{"value1":5.0,"value2":2.5,"value3":"2019-10-24T15:26:00.000Z","modifier":[]}
```

With this regex I can extract the value3 (019-10-24T15:26:00.000Z) correctly

```
sed -e 's/^.*"endTime":"\([^"]*\)".*$/\1/'
```

How can I extract the "value2" result, a string without double quotes?

> **I need to do with sed so can’t install jq. That’s my problem**

Comment: If you already have structured information why don't you use a `JSON` parser instead? Your approach with `sed` is prone to errors, really (think about linebreaks, escaped quotes, etc.).

Comment: `jq '.value2' <<< "$jsonstring"`

Comment: A possible duplicate of [Parsing JSON with Unix tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955505)

Comment: Not a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just run `jq` a *Command-line JSON processo*r

```
$ json_data='{"value1":5.0,"value2":2.5,"value3":"2019-10-24T15:26:00.000Z","modifier":[]}'
$ jq '.value2' <(echo "$json_data")
2.5
```

with the key `.value2` to access the value you are interested in.

> This link summarize why you should **NOT** use, regex for parsing json
>   (the same goes for XML/HTML and other data structures that are in
>   theory can be infinitely nested)
>
> [Regex for parsing single key: values out of JSON in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8750127/regex-for-parsing-single-key-values-out-of-json-in-javascript)

If you do not have `jq` available:

you can use the following GNU `grep` command:

```
$ echo '{"value1":5.0,"value2":2.5,"value3":"2019-10-24T15:26:00.000Z","modifier":[]}' | grep -zoP '"value2":\s*\K[^\s,]*(?=\s*,)'
2.5
```

using the regex detailed here:

```
"value2":\s*\K[^\s,]*(?=\s*,)
```

**demo:** https://regex101.com/r/82J6Cb/1/

**This will even work if the json is not linearized!!!!**

With `python` it is also pretty direct and you should have it installed by default on your machine even if it is not python3 it should work

```
$ cat data.json 
{"value1":5.0,"value2":2.5,"value3":"2019-10-24T15:26:00.000Z","modifier":[]}
$ cat extract_value2.py 
import json

with open('data.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    print(data["value2"])
$ python extract_value2.py 
2.5
```

Comment: Not very useful. What package does `jq` come in? On what system is that the name? It certainly doesn't come in any default packages on Ubuntu or Debian. Maybe link to a download page.

Comment: I need to do with sed so can’t install jq. That’s my problem.

Comment: @GuifIf you might want to state that in your question to stop the deluge of downvotes and close votes coming it's way. Also explain there why it has to be sed rather than awk (another tool that comes as standard on all UNIX installations).

Comment: @GuifIf: I have added on top of a `grep` solution a `python` one. So you should have enough tools available to extract it now. Cheers

Comment: For the regex statement I would suggest you add a character class around the final `,` and also include the `}` character (i.e `[,}]`). This way you can still capture the last object in the list.  

For example:

`"modifier":\s*\K[^\s,]*(?=\s*[,}])`

Answer (score 14):

With GNU sed for `-E` to enable EREs:

```
$ sed -E 's/.*"value3":"?([^,"]*)"?.*/\1/' file
2019-10-24T15:26:00.000Z

$ sed -E 's/.*"value2":"?([^,"]*)"?.*/\1/' file
2.5
```

With any POSIX sed:

```
$ sed 's/.*"value3":"\{0,1\}\([^,"]*\)"\{0,1\}.*/\1/' file
2019-10-24T15:26:00.000Z

$ sed 's/.*"value2":"\{0,1\}\([^,"]*\)"\{0,1\}.*/\1/' file
2.5
```

The above assumes you never have commas inside quoted strings.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this :

```
creds=$(eval aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --region us-east-1 --secret-id  dpi/dev/hivemetastore --query SecretString --output text )
passwd=$(/bin/echo "${creds}" | /bin/sed -n 's/.*"password":"\(.*\)",/\1/p' | awk -F"\"" '{print $1}')
```

it is definitely possible to remove the AWK part though ...

Answer (score 0):

if your data in 'd' file, try gnu sed

```
sed -E 's/[{,]"\w+":([^,"]+)/\1\n/g ;s/(.*\n).*".*\n/\1/' d
```

Answer (score 0):

#### To extract all values in proper list form to a file using sed(LINUX).

```bash
sed 's/["{}\]//g' <your_file.json> | sed 's/,/\n/g' >> <your_new_file_to_save>
```

- ```
  sed 's/regexp/replacement/g' inputFileName > outputFileName
  ```
- In some versions of sed, the expression must be preceded by `-e` to indicate that an expression follows.
- The `s` stands for substitute, while the `g` stands for global, which means that all matching occurrences in the line would be replaced.
  I've put `[  ]` inside it as elements that you wanna remove from `.json` file.
- The pipe character `|` is used to connect the output from one command to the input of another.
  Then, the last thing I did is substitute `,` and add a `\n`, known as line breaker.

#### If you want to show a single value see below command:

```bash
sed 's/["{}\]//g' <your_file.json> | sed 's/,/\n/g' | sed 's/<ur_value>//p'
```

- `p` is run; this is equivalent to `/pattern match/! p` as per above; i.e., "if the line does not match `/pattern match/`, print it". So the complete command prints all the lines from the first occurrence of the pattern to the last line, but suppresses the ones that match.