# IBM Qradar CE V7.3.3 Integration with nextcloud

Tags: integration, nextcloud, qradar

i have been working on my research about how effective IBM Qradar SIEM tools to protect private cloud against APT attack. I use Nextcloud as my private test cloud, that have been installed on ubuntu server. i want to ask about how to integrate Nextcloud with IBM Qradar, so Qradar can receive logs from Nextcloud and can parse the event.

Answer (score 0):

Nextcloud uses JSON and SIEM solutions can parse JSON by using regex. Here an example.

[Regex for parsing single key: values out of JSON in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8750127/regex-for-parsing-single-key-values-out-of-json-in-javascript)