# How can I extract specific lines from a json document?

Tags: json, shell, visual-studio-code, vim, sublimetext3

I have a json file with thousands of lines and 90 json objects.
Each object come with the following structure:

```
{
        "country_codes": [
            "GB"
        ],
        "institution_id": "ins_118309",
        "name": "Barclaycard (UK) - Online Banking: Personal", // I want to extract this line only
        "oauth": true,
        "products": [
            "assets",
            "auth",
            "balance",
            "transactions",
            "identity",
            "standing_orders"
        ],
        "routing_numbers": []
    },
```

For the ninety objects, I would like to delete all the lines and keep only the one with the name of the institution.

I guess that I will have to use a regex here?
I'm happy to use with vim, sublime, vscode or any other code editor that will alow me to do so

How can I extract these lines so I will stay with the following 90 lines?

```
 "name": "Barclaycard (UK) - Online Banking: Personal",
 "name": "Metro Bank - Commercial and Business Online Plus",
 ...
 ...

 "name": "HSBC (UK) - Business",
```

Comment: Assuming you aren't particular about the formatting, you should use something like `jq` to write the filtered objects to a new file, then replace the old with the new.

Comment: If you want to copy those lines, just do `:sort`, search for a known word `/Baclay`, yank `Vjjjjjy` and finally `u` to undo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you must use a code editor, then in Vim you can delete all lines *not*
matching a pattern with: `:v/^\s*"name":/d`

The above pattern says:

- `^` line begins with
- `\s*` zero or more white spaces
- `"name:"` (pretty explanatory)

**Although it's better to use a dedicated tool for parsing json files
rather than regex as [json is not a 'regular
language'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8751940/14467607).**

#### Bonus

If you do end up doing it in Vim, you can finish up by left align all the lines, do `:%left` or even just `:%le`.

Answer (score 2):

That doesn't sound like the job for a text editor or even for regular expressions. How about using the *right tool for the job™*?

```
# print only the desired fields to stdout
$ jq '.[] | .name' < in.json

# write only the desired fields to file
$ jq '.[] | .name' < in.json > out.json
```

See https://stedolan.github.io/jq/.

If you really want to do it from a text editor, the simplest is still to filter the current buffer through a specialized external tool. In Vim, it would look like this:

```
:%!jq '.[] | .name'
```

See `:help filter`.

---

FWIW, here it is with another *right tool for the job™*:

```
:%!jj \\#.name -l
```

See https://github.com/tidwall/jj.

Answer (score 1):

you can use grep eventually :

`grep '^\s*"name":' your_file.json`

Answer (score 0):

In VSC

- select `institution_id`
- execute **Selection** > **Select All Occurenses**
- `Arrow Left`
- `Ctrl+X`
- `Esc`
- `Ctrl+V`

Comment: It's not clear which editor/software these instructions are for.

Answer (score 0):

In vscode (although I would think it is the same for any regex-handling editor), use this Find:

```
^(?!\s*"name":.*).*\n?|^\s*
```

and replace with nothing.  See [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/PfE2RE/1).

`^(?!\s*"name":.*).*\n?` : get all lines that are not followed by `"name":...` including the newline so that line is completely discarded.

`^\s*` gets the whitespace before     `"name":......` - also discarded since we are replacing all matches with nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing JSON in Vim natively:

```
call getline(1, '$')
    \ ->join("\n")
    \ ->json_decode()
    \ ->map({_, v -> printf('"name": "%s",', v.name)})
    \ ->append('$')
```

NB. Line continuation is only available when sourcing script from file. If run interactively then type command on a single line.